# Can I run more than one services with docker-compose in one command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have read https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/, and I found that I can run a single service like `web` service here:

```
docker-compose run web
```

Can I run in a single line two or more services like this?

```
docker-compose run web, backup
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Currently `docker-compose run` does not allow specifying multiple services, and there aren't any plans to do so either due to the way `docker-compose run` is designed.

There are other ways to achieve a similar result:

- Use the [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) directive to specify that the `web` service depends on the `backup` service (or vice versa). It may be useful to [create a new docker-compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files) for this.
- Use `docker-compose up web backup` instead of `docker-compose run`
- Run it in separate commands like `docker-compose run web` and `docker-compose run backup` in another shell.
- Merge the `web` and `backup` services into a single service in your `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: `depends_on` was enough for my needs. Running two parallel docker-composers gave me a weird error: `dial tcp: lookup service on 127.0.0.1:53: server misbehaving.`

Answer (score 3):

Version docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c allows it using the sintax below:

```
docker-compose up -d SERVICE1 SERVICE2
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be more convenient for you to use  [profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/).